# 'darwin-arm64v8' binaries cannot be used on the 'darwin-x64' platform

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

I am trying to deploy functions to firebase using my Mac M1, for which it was required to do an `npm install` to install packages in `node_modules/`.
I am getting this error:

```
Error: 'darwin-arm64v8' binaries cannot be used on the 'darwin-x64' platform. Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp' directory and run 'npm install' on the 'darwin-x64' platform.
    at Object.hasVendoredLibvips (/Users/ali/Desktop/tajir/backend-mvp/appengine/back-end-flex/node_modules/sharp/lib/libvips.js:80:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ali/Desktop/tajir/backend-mvp/appengine/back-end-flex/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:7:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1136:30)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1394:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1024:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1338:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Usually someone having a Mac M1 would have this issue. The Mac M1 processor is `arm64`. There was a solution posted [here](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2678) which requires to change terminal architecture to `arch -x86_64 zsh` which I did not want to do.

So, that's the workaround I was able to discover (some of the steps also mentioned in the error):

```
rm -rf node_modules/sharp
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=darwin sharp
```

Comment: How does this work with something like `electron-universal` which requires support for both `x86_64` and `arm64`?

Comment: I did this terminal architecture change that you mentioned cause I needed to run pentaho from M1 Mac. How can I undo this? I deleted the newly created intel terminal profile but it does not solved the error.

Comment: @Slbox the version you should install for `@electron/universal` should depend on the architecture of your computer's processor, as this is just a package to make apps for both platforms. I am assuming you're asking whether you should install the `arm64` version or `x86` etc.

Comment: @Phaki If the architecture of your processor was `arm64` before, then you can undo the thing using the same command you used to make it `x86`, but you must write `arm64` instead. Unfortunately the website link I gave no longer exists :-(

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that @AliSajjad. I just fixed the link.

Comment: For **ARM CPUs**, such as **M1** use this:
`npm install --cpu=arm64 --os=darwin sharp`
[Official doc](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#npm-v10)

Answer (score 7):

this works for me

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install

```
npm install --platform=darwin --arch=x64 sharp
npm rebuild --platform=darwin --arch=arm64 sharp
```

Answer (score 6):

For me, all I had to do was:

```
brew reinstall vips
```

then do a clean install of the project.

Comment: Hi, what is vips?

Comment: In my case the error message contained something about "vips" and reinstalling it helped me.

Comment: @dcxst "A fast image processing library with low memory needs."

https://github.com/libvips/libvips
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/vips

Comment: `brew reinstall vips` helped me (mac m1 pro), thanks

Answer (score 4):

My answer is not related to deploying functions to firebase, but I had that exact same error:

```
Error: 'darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'darwin-arm64v8' platform. Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp' directory and run 'npm install' on the 'darwin-arm64v8' platform.
```

when I tried to run a project with a mac M1 using a version of node that was incompatible.

I tried to run the project with version 16 when the project actually require version <=14.

So if anyone has this problem might be worth checking the node version

Comment: Do you mean the required version of node might be <=14 or you're talking about the package?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I got it fixed with removing `node_modules` and installing them again.

```
Error: 'darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'darwin-arm64v8' platform. 
  Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp' directory and run 'npm install' on the 
  'darwin-arm64v8' platform.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which occured on a pod install. Unfortunately none of the above answers worked. What fixed the issue for me was rebuilding sharp with NPM.

```
npm rebuild sharp
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on MacOs. This happened after you update MacOs version. Try as below

```
nvm uninstall 14
nvm install 14
yarn
```

##### Notes.

If you got error `nvm: Cannot uninstall currently-active node version`. Try to switch to another node version and uninstall version you want to, then go back to version you want to use.

EX:

```
// Temporary switch to another version
nvm install 15

// Now you can uninstall version 14
nvm uninstall 14

// Reinstall version 14
nvm install 14

// Everything should work now.
yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error today spinning up a Gatsby app locally. Reverting to the Node version that I used when installing the originally Gatsby application worked for me to get past it. Switched from Node v16 to v14.20.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with another package built on sharp and needed to uninstall VIPS

```
npm uninstall MY_PACKAGE
brew uninstall vips
npm install MY_PACKAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a **yarn solution**, here it is after some hours of searching:

```
rm -rf node_modules/sharp
SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 npm_config_arch=arm64 npm_config_platform=darwin yarn add sharp
```

This is the platform and arch for mac silicon. You may need to change it if you're on different hardware. The right ones will be named in the error log

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:`yarn add sharp --ignore-engines` with macos and node18