# Error:'darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'darwin-arm64v8' platform

Tags: node-modules, sharp, darwin

I am facing this error when I am trying to do a git push on Intellj.
It's a similar issue to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814180/darwin-arm64v8-binaries-cannot-be-used-on-the-darwin-x64-platform)  but opposite ( That one is 'darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'darwin-arm64v8')
I have tried all the solution from that post but the git push still throwing the same error.
Below is the error I recevied when I do a git push.

```
Error in "/Users/xxx/Projects/cpss/node_modules/gatsby-transform
er-sharp/gatsby-node.js": 'darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the
'darwin-arm64v8' platform. Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp' directory and
run 'npm install' on the 'darwin-arm64v8' platform.
Error:'darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'darwin-arm64v8' platform. 
Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp' directory and run 'npm install' on the 
'darwin-arm64v8' platform.
```

I have tried to delete the node_modules/sharp and run npm install but it does not work.

Can someone explains to me how can I run npm install on 'darwin-arm64v8' platform?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69634633/3210677) resolved it for me:

Run `brew reinstall vips`. Then delete the `node_modules` folder and install all dependencies again (with `npm install` or `yarn`).

Answer (score 0):

delete the node_modules/sharp and run `npm install --arch=arm64 --platform=darwin sharp`

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#cross-platform